# Can I create a component on a seperate HTML page and embed that page into my main HTML page, without it interfering with CSS styles of main page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a "our team" grid for my website, yet I'm trying to do it through bootstrap. Because I didn't use bootstrap for my website's styling, by including bootstrap, it highly interferes with the website styling.

Is it possible to create a new HTML page, embed Bootstrap there and code the our team grid there, and then embed that into my main HTML page, in order to minimize the bootstrap interference?

Comment: Did you tried `<iframe>`?

Comment: `<iframe>` sounds like a perfect solution for you, but another thing you could do is just get the style you need from Bootstrap and then rename the classes to your own.